# Sphinx Voice Activity Detection

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

So I'm trying to write a simple program that will detect voice activity with a .wav file using the CMU Sphinx library.

So far, I have the following

```
SpeechClassifier s = new SpeechClassifier();

s.setPredecessor(dataSource);
Data d = s.getData();

while(d != null) {
    if(s.isSpeech()) {
        System.out.println("Speech is detected");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Speech has not been detected");
    }

    System.out.println();
    d = s.getData();
}
```

I get the output "Speech is not detected" but there is Speech in the audio file. It seems as if the getData function is not working the way I want it to. I want it to get the frames and then determine whether the frames (`s.isSpeech()`) contain speech or not.

I'm trying to have multiple outputs ("Speech is detected" vs "Speech is not detected") for each frame. How can I make my code better? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert DataBlocker before SpeechClassifier:

```
 DataBlocker b = new DataBlocker(10); // means 10ms
 SpeechClassifier s = new SpeechClassifier(10, 0.003, 10, 0);
 b.setPredecessor(dataSource);
 s.setPredecessor(b);
```

Then it will process 10 millisecond frames.

Comment: Thank you! But after adding that, it is now breaking at the last line (d = s.getData()). Am I supposed to get rid of the getData() method altogether? I added the DataBlocker and modified SpeechClassifier like your advised above.

Comment: getData() should stay. What do you mean by "breaking at the last line"?

Comment: I edited my post above. Sorry if my problem seems straightforward. I feel like it should be but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: You need a different constructor `new SpeechClassifier(10, 0.003, 10, 0);` then it will work, see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! One more question, when speech is not detected I get the output "speech has not been detected at 1" twice and then "speech has been detected at 2". (So that's the first 3 lines) all of the "no speech detected" is repeated